what's the purpose of this microstrip track on a RF PA evaluation board?
I'm building a RF amplifier for CC1101 using PA2460.
There is an evaluation board layout in amplifier's datasheet.
What I don't understand is the purpose of the following microstrip track (ML1), is it used as an inductor with C11 and C12 to form a pi filter? If so, can I replace it with an inductor?

Here is the layout of the board

(including useful comment) The datasheet doesn't specify the frequency range for the reference layout, but the amplifier IC operates in the 130 MHz to 500 MHz band. The amplifier module I want to build operates at 433 MHz. The reason I ask this question is that I want to know how to modify the design if I use a different board (like a 4-layer board). The evaluation board layout is on a 1.2 mm FR4 board. Using components like inductors is clearly more flexible compared to a trace on the PCB. (/include comment)

A short length of high impedance line like ML1 does behave like an inductor at low frequencies, when its electrical length is much less than λ/4. As it approaches that length, their behaviour diverges, and at that length, the behaviour is totally different.
It's more likely to be used as impedance matching between the device and 50 ohm line, rather than a filter.
You can replace it with an inductor and a small redesign if your frequency is low enough, and ML1 is too big for your layout. However, most people will just use the reference layout in the data sheet unless there is very good reason to do otherwise.
For a more quantitative answer, you need to give the frequency range you want the amplifier to work over, and the length of the line in SI units of length or time.
(edit) Guessing line dimensions from the substrate thickness of 1.2 mm and 50 Ω line width, it appears to be about 25 mm, which means a λ/4 frequency of O(6 GHz). Operation at or below 500 MHz means it's practically all inductor, which means you could approximate it with an inductor if you wanted. Even going to a 4 layer board, you could duplicate the exact layout by using 1.2 mm to the ground plane below that line, by choosing core/prepreg thicknesses appropriately. Or you could change the width of the line to match the new substrate thickness. There are calculators available to convert from lengths of transmission line to effective low frequency inductance. (/edit).

The datasheet doesn't specify the frequency range for the reference layout, but the amplifier IC operates in the 130 MHz to 500 MHz band. The amplifier module I want to build operates at 433 MHz. The reason I ask this question is that I want to know how to modify the design if I use a different board (like a 4-layer board). The evaluation board layout is on a 1.2 mm FR4 board. Using components like inductors is clearly more flexible compared to a trace on the PCB.

@liyuqihxc see addition to answer
